# How to calculate $2^{(p^p-1)/2}$ modulo $p$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How to calculate $2^{(p^p-1)/2}$ modulo $p$?

I tried to write  $\frac{p^p-1}{2}$ as $(p-1)*\frac{p^{p-1}+...+p^2+p+1}{2}$ to use Fermat's little theorem so that  $2^\frac{p^p-1}{2}=(2^{\frac{p^{p-1}+...+p^2+p+1}{2}})^{p-1}$≡ 1 (mod p).

But then $2^{\frac{p^{p-1}+...+p^2+p+1}{2}}$ would not be an integer.

Any help would be grateful

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: @mathslayer Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%242%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7Bp-1%7D%7B2%7D%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Amodulo%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1), I found the relevant AoPS thread [a tricky number theory problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2541060p21657191).

Comment: Please do *not* blank your question. Remember that questions benefit everyone on this site, including people who might be reading your question years after you have posted.

Comment: Also please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Do not vandalize your own question (or anyone else's!). This is especially inconsiderate to anyone who has taken the time to provide an answer. ... I have rolled your question back to its previous state.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is trivially $0$ when $p=2$.

When the prime $p\geq 3, $
$p^{p-1}+...+p^2+p+1$ is **odd** and hence $\frac{p^{p-1}+...+p^2+p+1}{2}$ is **not** an integer and the argument fails.

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \quad \quad  p^p-1=(p-1)\left(p^{p-1}+p^{p-2}+\cdots+1\right)\\
&\Rightarrow \quad 2^{p^p-1}=\left(2^{p^{p-1}+p^{p-2}+\cdots+1}\right)^{p-1}\equiv 1 \quad  \pmod p
\quad \textrm{ (By FLT)} \\   &\Rightarrow \quad \left(2^{\frac{p ^p-1}{2}}\right)^2 \equiv 1 \quad(\bmod p)\\&\Rightarrow  \quad  2 ^\frac{p ^{p-1}}{2} \equiv \pm 1 \quad(\bmod p) \end{aligned}
$$

For examples,

$$
\begin{aligned}
&2^{\frac{3^3-1}{2}}=2^{13} \equiv -1 \quad(\bmod 3)\\
&2^{\frac{7^7-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \quad (\bmod 7)
\end{aligned}
$$
As @Giulio R suggested, when $2$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $$n^2\equiv 2 \quad  \pmod p,$$ then
$$2 ^\frac{p ^{p-1}}{2} \equiv \left(n^{2}\right)^\frac{p ^{p-1}}{2}\equiv n ^{p^{p}-1} \equiv 1 \quad(\bmod p), $$
otherwise, $$2 ^\frac{p ^{p-1}}{2} \equiv -1 \quad(\bmod p) $$

Comment: yes but you can continue, the answer will be $+1$ when $2$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ and $-1$ otherwise, i.e. $(-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}$

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.